# How to profile a piece of code? VS2013 C++

Tags: c++, profile

I can profile the complete application by clicking "Actions, Start profiling" in [performance explorer](http://prntscr.com/58brkb).

But I wish to profile only a piece of code, so I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770081/2301594) and came up with this code:

```
StartProfile(PROFILE_PROCESSLEVEL, PROFILE_CURRENTID);
testcode();
StopProfile(PROFILE_PROCESSLEVEL, PROFILE_CURRENTID);
```

so I use the "Start With Profiling Paused" but the profiler never starts profiling.

I've tried all levels (PROFILE_GLOBALLEVEL, PROFILE_PROCESSLEVEL and PROFILE_THREADLEVEL) - none of them work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, are you sure execution reaches those lines?

Comment: Try adding an extra `StopProfile` before the `StartProfile`. And use `PROFILE_GLOBALLEVEL`. And try attaching the profiler afterwards instead of 'Start with profiling paused'. That worked for me with the .NET API wrapper.

Comment: Hmm, darn. I guess that also rules out starting profiling from the IDE, then pausing profiling really fast before it reaches your code?

Comment: First two suggestions I have already tried. The third means that I would have to somehow pause my app - which I would rather not do. Anyway, I've switched to [AMD's CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/). It probably can't profile only a piece of code, but is at least faster.